# Make Dynamic Grid Items Start From Left

Tags: css, grid

Maybe this is a trivial question, but I am still learning CSS Grid. I have a problem with CSS Grid items placement, where the items are dynamic.

When I have many items, it is okay :

[image]

When I have one / two items, it centers.

[image]

I want it to start from the left.

My code :

```
.container {
  padding: 16px 24px;
  display: grid;

  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;

}
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Did you tried "align-items: start;"?

Comment: Yes I tried, but still the same

Comment: Maybe post your HTML and styles for the cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix grid and flex rules in some instances.
For this one, try:

`justify-content: flex-start`

When you have row-oriented items, it controls their horizontal alignment.

`align-items: center` will - by default - given the default flex rule is rows - center items vertically - but not horizontally.

You can read more on it here:

https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp